# How to parse TokenName to Integer

Tags: plutus, on-chain

I have information encoded in the `TokenName` of an asset. These token names represent integers.

According to the Plutus source code, the `TokenName` is of type `BuiltinByteString`. How can I parse it to type Integer in the on chain code ? In short I am looking for a Plutus-pendant of the Haskell `read`, but one that returns a `Maybe Integer`.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with the same thing, just going the opposite direction, `Slot -> TokenName` (`Slot` is just an `Integer` under the hood). After a bunch of pain I ended up just coding my own parsing logic:

```
-- Simplified business code here:
{-# INLINEABLE dcForSlot #-}
tokenNameForSlot :: Slot -> TokenName
tokenNameForSlot slot = TokenName $ Builtins.encodeUtf8 $ intToString $ getSlot slot

{-# INLINEABLE intToString #-}
intToString :: Integer -> Builtins.String
intToString i = Prelude.foldr Builtins.appendString "" strings
  where
    ints = intToInts i
    strings = map (Builtins.charToString . intToChar) ints

{-# INLINEABLE intToInts #-}
intToInts :: Integer -> [Integer]
intToInts i
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger a 0) = [b]
  | otherwise = (intToInts a) ++ [b]
  where
    (a, b) = divMod i 10

{-# INLINEABLE intToChar #-}
intToChar :: Integer -> Haskell.Char
intToChar i
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 0) = '0'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 1) = '1'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 2) = '2'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 3) = '3'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 4) = '4'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 5) = '5'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 6) = '6'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 7) = '7'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 8) = '8'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 9) = '9'
  | otherwise = '0' -- Fix this
```

Feel free to try and reverse this to get what you want. It might be easier going the other direction, I don't have time rn to figure out what it would look like but I feel your pain, so I thought I'd share.

Comment: What does 'intToInts' do ?

Comment: It splits all the digits of the integer:
`intToInts 5701 == [5, 7, 0, 1]`

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I will post my solution as soon as I have it. It's crazy that we have to use such work arounds on Plutus.

Comment: Yeah. It's young still. There's plenty of room for people to add libraries. There's a big chance I missed some tools as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is slow but works.

```
{-# LANGUAGE  OverloadedStrings  #-}

module StackExchange where

import Prelude
import PlutusTx.Builtins.Class
import PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal
import Data.ByteString hiding (map)
import Data.Char

s = stringToBuiltinByteString "123"

bsToMaybeInteger :: BuiltinByteString -> Maybe Integer
bsToMaybeInteger str
  | Prelude.all (\x -> x >= 48 && x <= 57) unpackedString = Just (Prelude.read (Prelude.map chr unpackedString) :: Integer)
  | otherwise                                             = Nothing
  where
    unpackedString = map fromEnum . unpack . fromBuiltin $ str
```

Can be tested in a `cabal repl` session like this:

```
λ> StackExchange.bsToMaybeInteger StackExchange.s
Just 123
```

Comment: Have you tried this in compiled on-chain code?

Comment: fair point, I have not done that yet... I guess there may be some slight modifications necessary.

Comment: Yeah. That's where I had the biggest headache, especially since the Plutus compiler doesn't give very helpful error messages.